# Finding xcode project name of a ported ionic app to ios to lauch multiple simulators

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, xcode10

As a school project, I'am working on a iOS port of a ionic chat app. After a lot of troubleshooting, I finally managed to make it work on one device. Now I want to use multiple simulators to test the chat capabilities of my app.([following this tutorial on medium](https://medium.com/@guilhermegirotto/launch-multiple-simulators-in-a-single-build-xcode-9-xcode-10-5c8d13f01376)).

But the problem arises on the *created launch script part* where I need to find my project name:

```
path=$(find ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<YOUR_PROJECT_NAME>-*/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -name "<YOUR_APP_NAME>.app" | head -n 1)
```

So I tried tried the command:

```
find ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Spiel* -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

and instead of returning only 1 projects it returns several ones:

```
/Users/soyanchardon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Spiel-azmvgnpavliucyaxeiykxemnwbpv
/Users/soyanchardon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Spiel-azmvgnpavliucyaxeiykxemnwbpv/Logs
/Users/soyanchardon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Spiel-azmvgnpavliucyaxeiykxemnwbpv/Index
/Users/soyanchardon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Spiel-azmvgnpavliucyaxeiykxemnwbpv/Build
/Users/soyanchardon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Spiel-bmjzcrhlutzmbahdmqohtaidhhyj
/Users/soyanchardon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Spiel-bmjzcrhlutzmbahdmqohtaidhhyj/Logs
/Users/soyanchardon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Spiel-bmjzcrhlutzmbahdmqohtaidhhyj/TextIndex
/Users/soyanchardon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Spiel-bmjzcrhlutzmbahdmqohtaidhhyj/Index
/Users/soyanchardon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Spiel-bmjzcrhlutzmbahdmqohtaidhhyj/Build
/Users/soyanchardon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Spiel-gfcbagyqlgghbkbfgbyqgscyprjn
/Users/soyanchardon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Spiel-gfcbagyqlgghbkbfgbyqgscyprjn/Logs
/Users/soyanchardon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Spiel-gfcbagyqlgghbkbfgbyqgscyprjn/TextIndex
/Users/soyanchardon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Spiel-gfcbagyqlgghbkbfgbyqgscyprjn/Index
/Users/soyanchardon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Spiel-gfcbagyqlgghbkbfgbyqgscyprjn/Build
```

As you can see I have 3 Spiel folders, and I don't know which one should I choose.

Also as an additional question, why is there 3 folders? I assume it was because of my previous failed attempts to port the app, but I really have no clue!

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete these folders from DerivedData and rebuild. Like this, you will have only one option to choose.

And yes, the problem comes from the previous attempts.